# Phonegap/SQLite no such table errors for CacheGroups, Caches, Origins, and DeletedCacheResources

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I have a PhoneGap application using SQLite.  My database and tables generated from code are being initialized and created properly and the application is running queries fine against these tables.

Strangely, I'm seeing the following errors in LogCat when running the application:

```
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: CacheGroups
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: Caches
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: Origins
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
```

From what I understand these are native database tables used by SQLite, but aren't being generated.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you have any success in resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you post your codes so it will be easier to find when the log is being generated.

Comment: We need more informations

Comment: *How* is your PhoneGap application *using* SQLite?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did not end up resolving this and had to move on to another project, so haven't had a chance to get back to it.  I was using the Javascript WebSQL API to store data for my application, which on my Samsung and HTC android phones used SQLite as the storage.

Answer (score 2):

Some people have been able to solve the problem using the steps mentioned http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html. It seems to me that this problem exists on certain versions of Android 2.2. I have incorporated this change in my code, though I'm still looking for Beta testers with to see if it actually works.